# Kate doesn't restore sessions

Tags: 22.04, kate

I'd like to have Kate (23.08.4 on Ubuntu 22) re-open my documents from last session.
Yet it doesn't seems to be working.

This is the setting
[image]

Comment: That might require KDE (kactivitymanagerd) and X11

Comment: @DanielT no idea why Wayland is so poorly supported on everything...

Comment: XSMP session restore may be going away https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-workspace/-/issues/35. If the files you need are constant, you could create a desktop shortcut to open `kate a.txt b.txt c.txt`. You could also just use VSCode

Comment: hmm I would assume that option got deleted. In ubuntu all "restore session" methods are considered a security threat and that option got removed when we stopped using unity.

Comment: Are you talking about your login session on your overall desktop, or a session specifically within Kate? Kate has a concept of a "session" that is something you specifically name and save a definition of, which is what that setting is referring to - not your overall desktop session: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kate/kate/fundamentals-using-sessions.html